# Get Youtube video by tags from specific user

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api, feed

I'm trying to get a youtube video from the $username with $tags:

```
$tags='detskij-sad-198';
require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
$authenticationURL = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
                          $username     = 'Schoolkharkovua',
                          $password     = '*****',
                          $service      = 'youtube',
                          $client       = null,
                          $source       = '*****',
                          $loginToken   = null,
                          $loginCaptcha     = null,
                          $authenticationURL);

$devkey = '*****';
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, '', '', $devkey);
$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
$query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
$query->setMaxResults(4);
$query->setVideoQuery($tags); // also i tried $query->category = $tags;
$query->setAuthor($username);
$videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($query->getQueryUrl(2));
```

$videoFeed returns no entry, although I know that the $username has a video with $tags and this code to work until mid-March

If I do query only by the $username or by $tags - I get the result.
What am I doing wrong?

PS. http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html return empty video feed too if I trying query by  "Keywords" and "Author name" simultaneously

Hhhhhmmmmm.... It seems that "google" no longer get the symbols "-" in tags

But

```
echo 'Tags: ' . implode(", ", $videoEntry->getVideoTags());
```

still emty, youtube api don't return video tags!

Guys help me get video tags from my video channel, please!

Comment: `-term` will interpreted as `NOT term` by Youtube API:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php?hl=de#Searching_for_Videos

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate your connection, YT returns an empty media$keywords object now (as of last Aug).

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Authentication

and here's their blog post about it...

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html

Comment: But I'm already authenticated by ClientLogin method, What else do I need authentication?